# Javascript click button function under certain div

Tags: javascript

This is the code of a button in one html page

```
<a class="btn" role="button" href="#">Click me</a>
```

I have this javascript code to click a button with a certain class

```
var clickBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn'); 
for(var i=0;i<clickBtn.length;i++)
{ 
clickBtn[i].click(); 
}
```

This code clicks every button with the class "btn" in ALL the page.
But there are some other buttons in the same page with the same class.
So i want my javascript code to be modifided to click
only a certain button in a certain div.

The code with the div is

```
<div class="inside">
<span>
<a class="btn" role="button" href="#">Click me</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Any idea of how can i modify my javascript code to click only the button inside that div??
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can try following jQuery code `$(".divClass.btn").on("click", handler)` or `$("#divID.btn").on("click", handler)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll()

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.inside  .btn')).forEach(btn => {      
   alert(btn.innerHTML)
   btn.click();
});
```

Or without es6:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inside  .btn')).forEach(function(btn) {
    alert(btn.innerHTML)
    btn.click();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcntpm6/)

Updated for your comment (Can you update your code that if there is an id in the span like  not to click the button?):

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inside  .btn')).forEach(function(btn) {

    if (btn.parentNode.id != 'clicked') {
        alert(btn.innerHTML);
        btn.click();
    }

});
```

or you can use querySelectorAll() with a `:not` condition to avoid the `if` check:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.inside span:not([id="clicked"]) .btn'))
    .forEach(btn => {
        alert(btn.innerHTML)
        btn.click();
    });
```

Comment: Very nice. Can you update your code that if there is an id in the span like     <span id="clicked">  not to click the button???

Comment: Edited it! @KwnstantinosNatsios

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-jQuery solution, you can use `getElementById` to get the div, and then `getElementsByClassName` to get all the buttons within that div.

```
var insideDiv = document.getElementById("inside");
var buttonsInsideDiv = insideDiv.getElementsByClassName();
```

Comment: But this div has only class. And even if i replace the error with the class and i run this  var insideDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("inside");
var buttonsInsideDiv = insideDiv.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for(var i=0;i<buttonsInsideDiv.length;i++)
{ 
buttonsInsideDiv[i].click(); 
}    this is not working.   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null

Answer (score 0):

```
var parentDiv = clickBtn[i].parentNode;

var clickBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn'); 
for(var i=0;i<clickBtn.length;i++)
{ 
var parentDiv = clickBtn[i].parentNode;
  if(parentDiv == yourDiv)
   {
    clickBtn[i].click(); 
   } 
}
```

I am not sure, var parentDiv = clickBtn[i].parentNode will work. But the idea is the same.